# Continuous function defined by infimum

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(y_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers and define $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by setting
>   $$f(x)=\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}}n|x-y_{n}|$$
>
> Show that if $(y_{n})$ has no accumulation point then $f$ is continuous.

This is not homework. I can not do anything good. But I can conclude that $f(y_{n})=0$, and if $f(x)=0$ then $x\in (y_{n})$. Moreover it is easy to see that in each interval we have finite member of $(y_{n})$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please always show attempts at homework solution when asking on MSE.

Comment: This is not homework. I can not do anything good. But I can conclude that $f(y_{n})=0$, and if $f(x)=0$ then $x\in (y_{n})$. Moreover it is easy to see that in each interval we have finite member of $(y_{n})$.

Comment: @Moh514 Whether it's homework or not, you should show some of your thoughts.  I've edited them in to this question.  Cheers!